# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #2](https://drones.stackexchange.com/election/2) on Drones and Model Aircraft has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: anonymous2]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://drones.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://drones.stackexchange.com/election/2) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5098981605507072).

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations to anonymous2, and thank you both for running in the election! I look forward to more good times here!